# How can I annotate a method with Spring Security so that a caller is required to have one of a list of roles?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Java annotations to grant permissions to a particular method. So far I have not found a way to make my method accessible to multiple roles. Single role works fine with `@Secured("ROLE_CUSTOMER")`. Is there a way to do `hasRole('role1','role2')`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found an exact solution to the problem:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER','ROLE_OFFICEADMIN','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')")
```

Comment: does this make any difference to have 'ROLE_' text before the role? This seems to working with me without 'ROLE_'.

Comment: Roles are different than authorities in that `ROLE_` will be added if not present.  See `hasRole` and `hasAnyRole` at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-common-built-in

Answer (score 11):

Just:

```
@Secured({"ROLE1", "ROLE2", "ROLE3"})
```

Comment: Just to mention that this is working as OR not as AND between this 3 roles.

Comment: If you are going to use this option, see the issue reported in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892152/are-multiple-roles-allowed-in-the-secured-annotation-with-or-condition-in-spr

Answer (score 7):

To make that happen I often use this

import this into your JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

and know you can use this to handle security like in if taglib

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

There is also another one like this to not permit those... i think it's HasNoRole

Anyway this works !

Comment: @Willie Wheeler import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;  Add this to your java file and then the code annotaions             @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER','ROLE_OFFICEADMIN','ROLE_EMPLOYEE')")   works like charm :)

Comment: Glad I could help ! and Yes you have to import the Taglibs, I forgot to add that.

Answer (score -2):

The grails "Secured" annotation is different form the spring "Secured" annotation. Grails takes an array of strings. Spring takes a weird security expression language.

so:

```
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
@Secured('hasAnyRole([\'FOO-ROLE\'])')
```

or:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured;
@Secured(['FOO-ROLE'])
```

Comment: Can you please mention why you suggested a solution using Grails??? Though the purpose being solved within spring owned library already. I believe grails is altogether a framework apart from spring.