# Are multiple roles allowed in the @Secured annotation with 'or' condition in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring and spring security 4 in my project.
I have to call my dao method with ROLE_USER or ROLE_TIMER_TASK.

Currently I am using this annotation -

```
 @Secured({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_TIMER_TASK"})
```

This @Secured annotation allowing only those users who have both role but I wanna call this method by user who have any one role from this.

Could it be possible if user have any one role from this roles and call this method?

Comment: Much after I answered this, I realized that the default behaviour of Secured is _or_, although configuration can change it to _and_. Well, I guess my answer is still valid.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For *or*, use a `@PreAuthorize` annotation instead:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_TIMER_TASK')")
```

In Spring Security version 4 the `ROLE_` prefix can be omitted:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('TIMER_TASK')")
```

Make sure you have pre- and post-annotations enabled in your security config.

Comment: Thanks for this solution but Now I am facing another issue. When this secured method called its generate exception that is - org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken  
I have used CAS authentication for Login.
So what can i do for this exception ?

Comment: @GouravSaklecha Does not seem related, ask a new question.

Answer (score 7):

To call the method by any of the role mentioned use:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_TIMER_TASK')")
```

and enable pre- and post- annotations in security Class :

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer by holmis83....

To enable pre- and post- annnotations for method security:

Java Config:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig {
// ...
}
```

Xml Config:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```